# new PloneFormGen Form Folder has Plain Text Format for Prologue and Epilogue

Tags: tinymce, plone, ploneformgen

When I create a new PFG Form Folder, the Prologue and Epilogue textareas come up with a default Text Format = Plain Text.  Is this intended?

If the user's default text editor is TinyMCE (both in /personalize_form and in portal_memberdata wysiwyg_editor), I would expect the Prologue and Epilogue to behave the same as a new Page content type, which comes up with TinyMCE.

When I look at Products.PloneFormGen-1.5.5 in content/form.py, the TextField('formPrologue') has a default_content_type = zconf.ATDocument.default_content_type, so it would seem that it would behave the same way as a normal Document content type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue due to a bad interaction between a bug in Archetypes and some changes to how the mimetype is determined in recent releases of TinyMCE.  If you're on Plone 4 you can upgrade to Products.Archetypes 1.6.6 or later to fix it (this Archetypes release is included in the latest Plone release, 4.0.5).

Comment: That's good to know!  The site unfortunately is Plone 3.3.4, and it has Products.Archetypes-1.5.16.  Not sure if the product can be upgraded on 3.3.4.  Also, the client reports that by default TinyMCE used to come up, and only recently did this default change.  Does this still sound like the same issue that would be fixed by Products.Archetypes 1.6.6?

Comment: Downgrading to Products.TinyMCE 1.1.7 should also work. Or you can help backport the Archetypes fix to the Archetypes 1.5.x series.

Comment: When I install Products.TinyMCE 1.1.7, I get this error on most pages:  http://pastie.org/1918795

Comment: Which Archetype fix do I need to backport?  I might give it a try.

Comment: Gaah!  Reinstalling TinyMCE Editor Support in portal_quickinstaller did the trick.